# PHP : How to run process separate from main process

Tags: php, cakephp-1.3

I have a function to import data from excel to database, I make this function to run on server so this function doesn't need to interact with client anymore, the client web browser just need to upload the excel file to server, after that, the task will be run just on server so if the browser closed by client, the function still run on server, i've got this, the problem is, when the browser is leave open by client, the browser will loading as long as the function still active.How can i made the browser not wait respond from server so the browser will not loading while the process is run on server.Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [message queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_queue) to offload the task of processing the file from the web server to another daemon running separately.

Comment: thank you for reply, can you give me some tutorial or example how to use this message queue?

Answer (score 0):

You can take the cheap and easy route of `exec`ing a process with `&` in the command line, causing it to be backgrounded. However, that gives you little control / status.

The right way to go about it IMO is to queue up these long-running tasks in a database, with some status info associated with them. Then have a dedicated process which runs separate from your webserver, checking the database for tasks, and performs them, updating the database with success/failure status.

Answer (score 0):

Look into using a queue such as Mseven's Queue Plugin:

[Msevens Queue Plugin](https://github.com/MSeven/cakephp_queue)

Or, if you want a more daemon based job, look into Beanstalkd. The queue plugin by mseven is pretty self explanatry though. Stay away from forking processes using &, it can get out of control.